# How to get taginput data from api

Tags: vue.js, buefy

I've got a bunch of tags stored in a database and can fetch them via an API. I've got no problems using my tags inside my template - except where I actually need them: in the taglist.

I'm an amateur and a newbie at vue, so I suspect the problem is not the Buefy element. The taglist works when I replace it with a regular array. More likely there is something missing in my understandig of how and when Vue gets the various data?

I've tried to simplyfy my code - hope it's not too simplified.

```
<template>
    <b-field label="Filter by tags">
        <b-taginput
            v-model="tags"
            :data="filteredTags"
            autocomplete                        
            field="tag"
            icon="label"
            type="is-warning"
            placeholder="Pick a tag"
            @typing="getFilteredTags"
            > {{ getTagger }}
        </b-taginput>
    </b-field>
</template>

<script>
import axios from "axios";
var _ = require('lodash');

export default {
    data: function() {
        return {
            tagger: [],
            filteredTags: tagger,
            tags: [],
        }
    },
    methods: {
       getFilteredTags(text) {
            this.filteredTags = tagger.filter((option) => {
                return option.tag
                    .toString()
                    .toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0
            })
        },
    },
    computed: {
        getTagger() {
        axios.get('url_to_working_api')
        .then(response => {
            const tagg = response.data.body;
            const resultArray = [];
            for (let key in tagg) {
                resultArray.push(tagg[key]);
                }
            this.tagger = _.sortBy(resultArray, ['tag']);
            console.log(this.tagger);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
        });                 
        }
    }, 
}
</script>
```

The tags does not display in the list, my console tells me that "tagger" is not defined in data() etc.

This is my amateur synchronous mind not getting the way Vue works, right? Please help me figure out what to read next. I've been going in circles on google for the better part of two days now :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning `tagger`, you need to assign `this.tagger` inside both `data` and `getFilteredTags()`. Hope it will work!

```js
    <template>
        <b-field label="Filter by tags">
            <b-taginput
                v-model="tags"
                :data="filteredTags"
                autocomplete                        
                field="tag"
                icon="label"
                type="is-warning"
                placeholder="Pick a tag"
                @typing="getFilteredTags"
                > 
            </b-taginput>
        </b-field>
    </template>

    <script>
    import axios from "axios";
    var _ = require('lodash');

    export default {
        data: function() {
            return {
                tagger: [],
                filteredTags: this.tagger,
                tags: [],
            }
        },
        mounted(): {
         this.getTagger()
        },
        methods: {
           getFilteredTags(text) {
                this.filteredTags = this.tagger.filter((option) => {
                    return option.tag
                        .toString()
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .indexOf(text.toLowerCase()) >= 0
                })
            },
           getTagger() {
                axios.get('url_to_working_api')
                .then(response => {
                 const tagg = response.data.body;
                 const resultArray = [];
                 for (let key in tagg) {
                    resultArray.push(tagg[key]);
                    }
                 this.tagger = _.sortBy(resultArray, ['tag']);
                 console.log(this.tagger);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });                 
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Saniya, but I'm afraid ut did not work. Errors: "expected to return a value in "getTagger comp.prop", "unexpected async action in getTagger comp.prop.", "unexpected side effect in getTagger (pointing at the "this" in this.tagger = _.sortBy(resultArray, ['tag]);

Comment: You need to call getTagger function on mounted, this will solve it

Comment: I have made changes in the above code snippet. You can try this out.

Comment: Thank you so much. That did work. Now, what I've learned from this is where to use "this", but I still don't quite understand why that function can't live in the computed props? Calling the function in the mounted props does make sense though - and I've been on that track but was not quite clever enough to get it working. But again; thanks a LOT!